# Python Speeding Up Retrieving data from extremely large string

Tags: python, regex, performance, python-2.6, substitution

See Down farther:

I have a list I converted to a very very long string as I am trying to edit it, as you can gather it's called tempString. It works as of now it just takes way to long to operate, probably because it is several different regex subs. They are as follow:

```
tempString = ','.join(str(n) for n in coords)
tempString = re.sub(',{2,6}', '_', tempString)
tempString = re.sub("[^0-9\-\.\_]", ",", tempString)
tempString = re.sub(',+', ',', tempString)
clean1 = re.findall(('[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+,[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+,'
                 '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+'), tempString)
tempString = '_'.join(str(n) for n in clean1)
tempString = re.sub(',', ' ', tempString)
```

Basically it's a long string containing commas and about 1-5 million sets of 4 floats/ints (mixture of both possible),:

```
-5.65500020981,6.88999986649,-0.454999923706,1,,,-5.65500020981,6.95499992371,-0.454999923706,1,,,
```

The 4th number in each set I don't need/want, i'm essentially just trying to split the string into a list with 3 floats in each separated by a space.

The above code works flawlessly but as you can imagine is quite time consuming on large strings.

I have done a lot of research on here for a solution but they all seem geared towards words, i.e. swapping out one word for another.

---

**EDIT:**
Ok so this is the solution i'm currently using:

```
def getValues(s):
    output = []
    while s:
        # get the three values you want, discard the 3 commas, and the 
        # remainder of the string
        v1, v2, v3, _, _, _, s = s.split(',', 6)
        output.append("%s %s %s" % (v1.strip(), v2.strip(), v3.strip()))         
    return output
coords = getValues(tempString)
```

Anyone have any advice to speed this up even farther? After running some tests It still takes much longer than i'm hoping for.

I've been glancing at numPy, but I honestly have absolutely no idea how to the above with it, I understand that after the above has been done and the values are cleaned up i could use them more efficiently with numPy, but not sure how NumPy could apply to the above.

The above to clean through 50k sets takes around 20 minutes, I cant imagine how long it would be on my full string of 1 million sets. I'ts just surprising that the program that originally exported the data took only around 30 secs for the 1 million sets

Comment: Split it into a list (`tempString.split(',')`), then operate on that. When the only tool you have is a regex, every problem starts to resemble a string.

Comment: Are all of the numbers to the same decimal precision?

Comment: It originally was a list, I converted it to a string to make the changes and then back to a list when the changes were done, I couldn't figure out how to get the changes I needed directly on a list

Comment: @Asad no saddly it's completely random/whatever the user happens to use/program, it's possible it could be an int too, i'll edit to clarify that

Comment: @Asad to be honest i'm not sure if the code I have now even works with ints as I have not tried it, but it does need to

Comment: numpy arrays could be used if you need to manipulate 20 millions floats efficiently

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, the below solution sped it up a lot, but i'm going to attempt NumPy and see if that helps more, I hear talk of people doing millions of numbers/second with it, and I know my computer shouldn't limit it much, 32gb ram and 350mb/s write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data:

```
>>> s = "-5.65500020981,6.88999986649,-0.454999923706,1,,,-5.65500020981,6.95499992371,-0.454999923706,1,,,"
>>> def getValues(s):
...     output = []
...     while s:
...         # get the three values you want, discard the 3 commas, and the 
...         # remainder of the string
...         v1, v2, v3, _, _, _, s = s.split(',', 6)
...         output.append("%s %s %s" % (v1, v2, v3))
...         
...     return output
>>> getValues(s)
['-5.65500020981 6.88999986649 -0.454999923706', '-5.65500020981 6.95499992371 -0.454999923706']
```

...once you have those parsed values as strings in a list you can do whatever else you need to do.

Or if you prefer, use a generator so you don't need to build the entire return string at once:

```
>>> def getValuesGen(s):
...     while s:
...         v1, v2, v3, _, _, _, s = s.split(',', 6)
...         yield "%s %s %s" % (v1, v2, v3)
>>> for v in getValuesGen(s):
...     print v
...     
... 
-5.65500020981 6.88999986649 -0.454999923706
-5.65500020981 6.95499992371 -0.454999923706
```

You may also want to try an approach that pre-splits your long list on the `,,,` set of commas instead of continually building and processing a set of shorter strings, like:

```
>>> def getValues(s):
...     # split your long string into a list of chunked strings
...     strList = s.split(",,,")
...     for chunk in strList:
...         if chunk:
...         # ...then just parse apart each individual set of data values
...             vals = chunk.split(',')
...             yield "%s %s %s" % (vals[0], vals[1], vals[2])
>>> for v in getValues(s10):
...     print v
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
-5.1  6.8  -0.454
```

At some point when you're dealing with huge data sets like this and have speed issues it starts to make sense to push things down into modules that are doing the hard work in C, like NumPy.

Comment: this seems to work perfectly, thanks for the help, I do have one question, every once in a while, once in every 10 sets or so I have this happen:
'-2.59999990463 \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t7.27999973297 0.780000150204', '-2.59999990463 7.34499979019 -0.519999921322', 
any advice on removing the \n's and \t's from the list entry, it seems to only happen at the beginning of the value like above, something I could possibly include in the def getValues to fix it? Once again thanks a ton for the help

Comment: Try cleaning that junk out using the `strip()` method on strings, like `"%s %s %s" % (v1.strip(), v2.strip(), v3.strip())`

Comment: Got it working perfectly, thank you so much for the help and it is quite a ton faster than what I had before. I'm going to try looking into J.F. Sebastians suggestion with NumPy and see if that can further improve my efficiency thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother you more, but just wondering if you had any more suggestions for speeding it up or a particular module I should look into, though I would prefer keeping it external module free, i.e. not have to download anything unless i have too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the memory drain without having to change anything in the regex would be to use the `re.finditer()` method instead of `re.findall()`. This would iterate through the values one-by-one rather than reading the entire string into a single list object. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer